# Oracle - does a view use a tables index if it exists

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization

I am a SQL guy, but am doing a stint in ORACLE land. Nothing wrong w/ expanding one's boundaries....

I have been given a view to a table. I do have permission to delete from that view.

```
Delete from vwGregsViewOnTable where SEQ = 12345
```

this takes 12 minutes. There are ~20M rows in the table, but 12 minutes?
I got a DBA involved and they confirmed that I am doing a table scan.

We scripted the table and that follows here in part...

```
CREATE TABLE SYT_SYALERTQUEUE
(
  IDRECMAIN          VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
  IDRECPARENT        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
  IDREC              VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
  SEQ                NUMBER(10),
.
.
.


CREATE INDEX SYNDX00000000000000000002277 ON SYT_SYALERTQUEUE
(SEQ)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE WV90NDX
```

It does appear that there is an index on the column I was told I should use.

in this case, vwGregsViewOnTable is the view on SYT_SYALERTQUEUE

My question is - how can I coax ORACLE into using the index. It doesnt seem to want to by default.

Comment: What is the definition of the view?  Is the view doing something that prevents the index from being used?  What is the query plan?  Are the optimizer's cardinality estimates accurate?  Or are there missing/ incorrect statistics on one or more objects?

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: You can force the Oracle's SQL-optimizer to use a certain index:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX (table indexname)*/ col1, col2
  FROM table
  WHERE blabla ;
```

This thingie here `/*+ INDEX (table indexname)*/` is called an [optimizer-hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm). Most of the time its not really wise to use that.